# VBA - Adding different formuilas in different columns

Tags: vba, excel

I've got at a table and have successfully created a vba code which adds a Vlookup formula and drags down the column.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
Range("H5:H" & lastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'XXX!$AA$5:$AM$2000,8,0)"
Range("H5:H" & lastRow).Value = Range("H5:H" & lastRow).Value
```

The issue I have now is I want to do the same to about 5 other columns with all different formulas... I have tried to replicate the above code but changing the columns and formula but keep getting errors or incorrect results.

i.e

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
Range("H5:H" & lastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'XXX!$AA$5:$AM$2000,8,0)"
Range("H5:H" & lastRow).Value = Range("H5:H" & lastRow).Value


lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
Range("G5:G" & lastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'XXX!$AA$5:$AM$2000,9,0)"
Range("G5:G" & lastRow).Value = Range("G5:G" & lastRow).Value
```

Any help will  be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: .... Honestly I don't know whats happened (and im quite embarrassed) but it appears to work??? just some formatting needs doing now. I swear ive been staring at this for hours and it didn't work..

Comment: Note that whether this code works or not, depends on what the `ActiveSheet` is. Explicitly qualify all `Cells` and `Range` (and `Rows`, although all sheets have the same number of rows so that one shouldn't matter) member calls with an explicit `Worksheet` object to make it work more reliably.